# Scheduled tweets and facebook share

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, share, scheduler

I create an application using Ruby on Rails. I wonder if there is any way for the users to set the date and time when the post should be shared in twitter and facebook.

I am aware of the way to normally share any post in twitter and facebook where the user will click on the share button and enter his/her login credentials for facebook/twitter  and then the post gets posted in their wall. I just want to automate this process through a scheduler.

Hope my question is clear. Please let me know If I have to explain in a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into something like [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque), you can specify for the tasks to fire at a later date. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with running this sort of thing in the background is that the Facebook API generally requires the user to confirm the share, so they need to be logged in to facebook at the time or log in at the time of the share request. I briefly looked into this a while ago and although I never implemented it I think the way to go is through the offline_access route.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to post something on twitter, you should use other things than the twitter button.

take a look at twitter authentication here

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=twitter

and later look here how to make the tweet action be delayed

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=delayed+job